# Button Styling between FireFox 5 & Chrome

Tags: html, css

Hello please take a look at the following: http://jsfiddle.net/9kHEs/

Look at it in FireFox 5 & then in chrome.

Notice in Firefox 5 back is nicely centered. In chrome the word "back" is a little to high. I tried using line-height to center but that has no effect.

What's the problem with the CSS? Why isn't "Back" being vertically centered equally across the two browsers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without spending more time playing with it, I'd venture to guess that it has to do with sub-pixel rounding (I've seen it with other elements and trying to center/align them), as your code looks alright.

Basically, a 12-pixel high font can't really center cleanly in a block that's 22px tall. Try making the box 24px tall and see what it does. If it still doesn't work, try setting the line-height to 24px (the same as the button) and see what you get.